# Markers for size, shape etc. on number words in Japanese

Tags: historical-linguistics, japanese, classifiers

Some languages, such as Japanese, mark number words with suffixes denoting size, shape, and other qualities (e.g., *ichi* (one) becomes *ippon* for one book). Why would such a linguistic practice develop?

Comment: These are actually combinations of the number words with special words called [_Classifiers_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word). Classifiers are common in many languages, and not just for counting; in some languages (like Navajo) they [inflect verbs to indicate the nature of the direct object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navajo_grammar#Classificatory_verbs). As to why such a practice would develop, that's mostly speculation; certainly the practice is useful, but so are most linguistic practices like subject-verb agreement or extraposition, but origins are right out.

Comment: @jlawler, your comment can be a good basis for a full-featured answer if expanded. The "why such a practice would develop" section can be easily salvaged if changed from motivational aspect (e.g. why has it ever appeared) to functional (what function it serves).

Comment: And I reckon the function it serves is very similar to the function that pronouns serve.

Answer (score 3):

[The *pon* in 'ippon'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word) is not actually a suffix (well, at least not according to the academic tradition of Russian japonology). It is [hon], a calque from [Chinese classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_classifiers) (aka a measure word) 本  [běn].

Anyone of the classifiers is a grammatical entity opposite, in a sense of [partialness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitive_case), to a  [term of venery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun#Terms_of_venery) and/or any collective noun.

The classifiers borrowed from Chinese also exist in [Burmese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burmese_numerical_classifiers), [Korean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_count_word) and, presumably, [Vietnamese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnamese_grammar#Classifier_position) languages.

Because *hon* is more likely a specific stem than an affix, the stricter term would be [agglutination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agglutination), which by itself is not a specific language practice at all. The examples of agglutination can be shown by such English nouns as *Batman, pineapple, hedgehog,* etc.

The change [h] makes turning itself into  [p] or [b] after [n] / [m] is [assimilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(phonology)), so a proper name for the phenomenon would be *assimilative agglutination.*

Why does this phenomenon occur?

I guess, because of combination of causes and effects, just like any existing phenomenon, like a coulour of grass or a human brain.

Comment: I think by "name for the phenomenon" he means "classifier".

Comment: ***I*** think by 'name for the phenomenon' I mean 'such a linguistic practice'  in the source question.

Comment: As for "Why?" -- assimilation is normal, in fact unstoppable. It's to be expected wherever it's possible in frequent use. Agglutinative morphology is extremely common -- roughly half the languages are standard SOV, which features agglutination. Both of these phenomena are time-tested strategies for phonology and grammar. Why numeric classifiers exist is another matter; they're not infrequent, but the easiest way to view a language with a classifier system is to simply think of all nouns as mass nouns. If you want a count noun, you use a classifier; that's all.

Comment: *-hon* is not a calque (a literal translation) but an actual loanword/foreign root, like *mono-* in English. It's from Middle Chinese *\*pənᴮ*, the ancestor of modern *běn*. The entire classifier system was borrowed wholesale from Chinese.  /h/ "becoming" /p/ isn't assimilation in this case; it's the other way around, the original Japanese pronunciation of *\*pən* is /pon/ (ほ used to be /po/ generally) and Japanese /p/ underwent [lenition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenition) except in protected position. /b/ is assimilation, due to voicing (from the original /p/, not from the modern /h/).

Comment: @leoboiko Your comment is just an elaboration of my statement where you are contradicting yourself first stating [h] becoming [p] isn't assimilation and then saying '[b] is assimilation. I wouldn't state so surely that '...the entire classifier system was borrowed', see e. g. here about the 'indigeneous Japanese classifiers' https://books.google.ru/books?id=I7PTXPq_nSAC&pg=PA257&lpg=PA257&dq=classifiers+in+middle++japanese&source=bl&ots=Yx6WKmNRiy&sig=eOlZKcSSpftSWugzWjm5_Gpvd-8&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj286ji4K7YAhWCAJoKHWvCBKYQ6AEIcTAM#v=onepage&q=classifiers%20in%20middle%20%20japanese&f=false